# How to get current location of user in android studio(java) using Dexter for runtime permission?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio version 3.5 and language is Java. I want to get user's location before which I am implementing runtime permissions using Dexter library: [Github Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter). I am able to grant and deny permission but I am not getting the user's location from location listener of location manager.

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        runtimePermission();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i("My Location: ", location.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

    }

    public void runtimePermission() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        Log.i("Permission", "Granted");
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",getPackageName(),null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
}
```

"Permission Granted" can be seen in Logcat but My location can't be seen. I guess, LocationListener isn't being invoked. Where am I going wrong?
Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

try easy permission library it's easy to implement
[Easy permission library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHbdDAOJHIU)